# Insert Image into MP4 video by PHP

Tags: php, video, mp4

I would like to insert still images into a mp4 sequence by PHP on server side, where the position of the placed image would move, for example I'd place an image into a photo frame with chroma-key color (or specified coordinates) in a room and the position of this photo frame would move in the video (if possible..).  Much similar to Facebook's "Friends Day" Video. See this **[example link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNWJ_XxfQfU)**.

Is there any class or function that would allow me to do so?

Check-ed out this previous question but seemed inconclusive? [Inserting an image inside a video at particular position via PHP and a video extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313139/inserting-an-image-inside-a-video-at-particular-position-via-php-and-a-video-ext)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There is no answer on how to do this with PHP alone but hopefully my answer was useful with some advice.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply as well as link to a sample tool.   I'll look into using FFmpeg per your steps, and also if my client would settle for stills frames with inserted image so we wound't have to apply perspective/distorts..

Comment: PS: If you don't need image to move (like TV Newsreader + thumbnail) then you can use the **[linked answer](http://video.stackexchange.com/a/12111)** to place image in one position for x amount of time. If there is movement like a car with logo then you need stills (grabs) and check each frame still for where image should be placed. This is where PHP becomes akward (but do-able depening on prepared video input). You need something like C++/C# or Java or AS3 for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're gunna need more than PHP**. You need to understand some things about pixel programming and its sub-category : computer vision.

Before I show you the reality check, let's assume the task is really as simple as to just *`"...Insert still images into a mp4 sequence by PHP"`*. What would you need?

**Try PHP :**
If you prepare your input footage to have something like a green colour box where image should be inserted then you can consider this **[PHP method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34943841/2057709)** for replacing the green pixels with user photo.

You will have to do this for every single frame. To get video broken down to single frame PNGs try a tool like FFmpeg...

**Try FFmpeg :**
First have FFmpeg installed on your server (there's even a FFmpeg to PHP connection, ie: send commands and receive the result). This will be used to extract from source, overlay images and later encode the new output video. You can see **[this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12111)** for overlaying images at specific positions.

In the snippet below, two input images are specified (`vid_frame1.png` is a video grab which needs an image to be inserted, `over_image1.png` is the to-be-overlaid image). `overlay=75:200` means position overlay image at 75px across (x) and 200px down (y).

```
ffmpeg -i vid_frame1.png -i over_image1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=75:200" new_frame1.png
```

As you can see, you have to specify the position so in a moving video (where placement position will change over time) you need to keep track of expected image position in each frame. In a 24 FPS video that means a possible 24 unique positions per second which might get tedious. You would run the above command 24 times, each time changing the `overlay`position.

**note :** If you install FFmpeg and use it with PHP then you could also do a **stdinput** / **stdoutput** process. This means you can output directly to video file instead of outputting "edited frame" PNGs. The video is generated as your program runs and when it's finish, there's a complete video file. This is too long to explain but you can information about it.

**The reality check...**
What you're talking about is called "dynamic video". You need a system in place to handle tasks like pixel tracking, perspective distortion and motion blur amongst others. This system would be a server based app (made using Java? or C#?). Here is one example of a **[dynamic editing tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVIZzWc4WDo)**. Also try coding something like this **[distortion tool](http://www.neuroproductions.be/uploads/blog/examples/envelope_distort/EnvelopeDistordTest.swf)** (found **[here](http://www.neuroproductions.be/experiments/envelope-distort-with-actionscript/)**) so if we take that green block idea, now you simply find the four corners of green block in source video frame and position those distort points to each corner and you have persective distortion etc. For motion blur via PHP (I never tried that but) there is Google search...